How to make a variable hidden in a header file
I have a template struct Distance that uses constexpr unsigned char mm2cm = 10
Since Distance is a template class, I must define mm2cm and Distance in a header file.
This header file is included by cpp files.
I want mm2cm to only be visible in this header file and not in the cpp files that include this header, ie:
Distance.hpp
constexpr unsigned char mm2cm = 10;

template <int offset>
struct Distance{
    int mm;
    int convToCm() const { return offset + mm2cm * mm; }
};

Main.cpp
#include "Distance.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    //I do not want to be able to use mm2mm outside Distance.hpp, as follows
    std::cout << (int)mm2cm << std::endl; 
    
}

One way I could solve this is using #define mm2cm 10 and #undef mm2cm at the beggining and end of the header file (instead of constexpr unsigned char mm2cm = 10.
However, a lot of people discourage the use of macros for reasons. This post lists some reasons why), and this website states that:

In general, the const keyword is preferred for defining constants and should be used instead of #define.

Another way I could solve this is by making mm2cmm a private static member of Distance.
However, in the actual, larger problem I am trying to solve, I have multiple variables that I only want to be visible in this header file, and making all of them private static members will make my class look ugly (in other words, there must be a better way than this solution).
I would be most grateful if someone could provide me the most optimal way to ensure mm2cm is only visible to Distance or only visible within this header file.

A prior edition of this post used a type template parameter. This has been changed to a non-type template parameter since the actual problem I am trying to solve uses a non-type template parameter.

OT: Why do you have the explicit conversion (the cast) when you print the value of mm2cm? Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion like that, you should take it as a sign that you're probably are doing something wrong.

just put it in a namespace called detail , that universally means private among C++ developers, as in, don't access it as i will change it in any day, it is an implementation detail

@Someprogrammerdude I used the C-style cast because std::cout << mm2cm << std::endl decided it wouldn't print out the actual integer value and instead print nothing (which i presume to be some character code due to it being an unsigned char). I could change it to a static cast but willing decided to use a c-style cast because it doesnt really hurt to do so.

aside from C++20 modules or #define, there is no way to declare something only in the header, (which is one of the reasons people pushed for C++20 modules)

@AhmedAEK so is modules a potential solution? I shall research now.

Ah, I didn't see that it was a char type. But then use static_cast<int>(mm2cm) instead. Yes it's more to write, but it's a good habit that will protect you in the future.

@AhmedAEK I like header files, they are easy to understand. Please don't tell me people are soon going to start using module instead of #include

@timmygeorge although modules are C++20, they are like the last thing that ever got implemented into any compiler, we even just got cmake support a few months ago in a cross-platform way, so it is hard to know what the future holds, but yes modules are the recommended way going forward, they cut down compile times greatly which is important for applications that take hours to compile. i don't see #include going away as it is he only way to interface with C headers, and libraries try to adopt both #include and import as usable methods to keep all users happy.

"making all of them private static members will make my class look ugly" - How so? You want them to be private and they are static in nature, so making them private and static constexpr would be my first choice.

@TedLyngmo Fair point. This is more of an opinion, but it feels like I am doing something wrong when I have a list of private static constexpr members that are only used once throughout my class. I think I will just do this then. Thanks.

@timmygeorge If they are only used once, then move them into the functions where they are used. int convToCm() const { constexpr int mm2cm = 10; return offset + mm2cm * mm; }

OT: To convert mm to cm you have to divide by 10, not multiply.

Agree with @TedLyngmo. I don't see any problem (esthetic or any other) to use as many private static constexpr members as you need (or use a local in a method if it is used only once).

Reviewing your requirements, this is the best I could come up with...
template <int offset>
struct Distance {
private:
    enum Constants : unsigned char {
        mm2cm = 10,
    };
public:
    int mm;
    int convToCm() const { return offset + mm2cm * mm; }
};

It hides the value in an enum, and can be used with other constants.
convToCm() looks like it is the wrong way (looks like it converts cm to mm.)
If mm2cm was an object or function, then it would inhibit the compiler's ability to optimize.
We could do a base class implementation, but that would still have the "ugly" multiple private / static members.
The use of integer offset as a template is awkward for the compiler.
Distance<10> value;
Distance<12> value2;

Requires the compiler to generate
int Distance<10>::convToCm() const;
int Distance<12>::convToCm() const;

Both of which have identical code except for the template parameter 10/12.  This would be more problematic if the objects were in a container, where std::vector< Distance<10> > requires different code to std::vector< Distance<12> >

Try this:
Distance.hpp
#ifndef DISTANCE_HPP
#define DISTANCE_HPP

template <typename UnitType>
struct Distance {
    UnitType mm;
    UnitType convToCm() const; // Declaration only
};

#endif // DISTANCE_HPP

Distance.cpp
#include "Distance.hpp"

namespace { // Anonymous namespace hides this constant
    constexpr unsigned char mm2cm = 10;
}

template <typename UnitType>
UnitType Distance<UnitType>::convToCm() const {
    return mm * mm2cm;
}

// Explicit instantiations (if needed)
template struct Distance<int>;
template struct Distance<float>;

Main.cpp
#include "Distance.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Distance<int> dist{100};
    std::cout << dist.convToCm() << std::endl; // Outputs 1000

    // The following line will fail to compile, as mm2cm is not visible:
    // std::cout << (int)mm2cm << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Sadly, I can still use mm2cm within main.cpp:

Modified the solution just now.

This makes it slightly harder to use mm2cm by forcing me to do std::cout << (int)DistanceDetails::mm2cm << std::endl;  within main.cpp. So mm2cm is not only visible within this header file

Modified answer again.

Changing the code from Distance<int> dist{100}; to Distance<unsigned int> dist{100}; to main.cpp results in a linker error  main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to 'Distance<unsigned int>::convToCm() const' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

In the actual problem I am trying to solve the class i am using has a non-type template parameter so I probably need to modify my post

@Saikat... This will require explicit instantiation of all the Distance types OP aims to support.

I have changed my post to now have a non-type template parameter
